# WordPress No muestra opción “Plantillas”

Tags: wordpress, template

Buenas noches.

Estoy realizando una plantilla para mi pagina llamada "servicios".

Realizo la copia de mi archivo "page.php" y creo un nuevo archivo al mismo nivel que "page.php" con el nombre: "page-servicios.php" o con el ID de la página "page-9.php" donde pego el contenido de mi archivo "page.php" añadiendo a inicio del mismo lo siguiente:

**<?php
/*
* Template Name: Servicios
* Template Post Type: servicio
*/
?>**

Pero al editar la página "servicios" en la sección de "Atributos de página" no muestra la opción para elegir "Plantillas". He intentado con mas opciones como:

**<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>**

**<?php
/*
* Template Name: Servicios
*/
?>**

Además de limpiado caché de mi navegador e iniciado sesión desde otros navegadores pero nunca se muestra la opción para elegir alguna plantilla.

También he visto que se trata de un BUG de Wordpress y e instalado un plugin (https://github.com/connorlacombe/WP-Clear-File-Cache )  que me otorga un botón para eliminar caché de wordpress sin que lograr que muestre la lista de plantillas.

También probé con este: https://gist.github.com/westonruter/6c2ca0e5a4da233bf4bd88a1871dd950  Pero el resultado es el mismo, sigo sin poder ver la lista de plantillas.

Espero me puedan ayudar ya que no encuentro alguna solución.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

Lo solucioné utilizando cualquiera de los dos plugins que indico en mi pregunta.

En mi archivo page-services.php al inicio lo dejé así:

/* Template Name: Servicios */

Eliminé mi archivo style.css principal y lo volví a crear, ejecuté el plugin y ya me mostró la lista de Plantillas al editar la página.